# Computing $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}\,dx.$

Tags: integration, limits, infinity

I'm computing $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}\,dx.$$

I have the proper antiderivative.

My first strategy in finding the limit involved splitting the limit into two, resulting in:

lim t>inf (-ln(x)/x) - lim t>inf (1/x), evaluated from 1 to t

I then used L'Hospital's rule to eliminate inf/inf in the first limit, and then evaluated each from 1 to t.

Using this method, I got 2.

Then I did the same thing, but kept the fraction intact: -(ln(x) + 1)/x.  Using L'HR here and then evaluating from 1 to t, I got 1 (which is the answer all the calculators give me).

What am I missing with the first method?  Did I not use L'HR properly (only on one of the limits). Obviously, the second method gets rid of the 1/x when using L'HR, but I can't find something that tells me I can't do that.  Even my professor is stumped right now.

Thanks

Comment: This is hard to read. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for typesetting on this site.

Comment: LHopital only applies to the limit as $t\to\infty$, not the value at $1$.  It's just a lucky coincidence that the second method yielded the correct answer.

Comment: You're right, lulu.  I apologize.  Never been here before, and my son suggested it as a good way to find an answer.

Comment: Brian, it is as t approaches infinity.  My poor typesetting is causing confusion.

Comment: Thank you all who are looking at this. My typesetting is terrible, I apologize. It seems my issue is an "order of operations" issue. I was using L'Hospital's rule before evaluating the function from 1 to t and then plugging in the limits of my integral. I should've plugged my ts in first, and then taken the limit. All fixed!

Comment: It would help if you displayed the anti-derivative.

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $\ln(x)=t$ to get $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-t}dt=\Gamma(2)=1$

Comment: I think using the Gamma function is slightly overkill, but it's a good answer :)

Comment: Yeah I know. But there I am merely using the definition of Gamma function. Otherwise the main helpful point to the op is that computing IBP with exponential function is easier than log.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: as that Gamma integral can be easily evaluated with IBP, it is really pretty basic (at which point, it becomes isomorphic to IBP with log).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left.-\frac{\log x}{x}\right\rvert^t_1+\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}= \lim_{t\to\infty}\left.-\frac{\log x}{x}\right\rvert^t_1\left.-\frac1x\right\rvert^t_1.$$
Now, both limits exist independently and
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\log t}{t} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac 1t = 0.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, since $\log 1 = 0$,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $a\gt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_1^\infty x^{-a}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\frac1{a-1}\tag2\\
&=\frac1{(a-1)^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}x^{-a}=\frac{\log(x)}{x^a}$
$(2)$: integrate
$(3)$: differentiate

---

A question was raised about the interchange of the integral and the derivative in step $(1)$. We can justify that with Fubini-Tonelli and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_1^\infty\int_a^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^t}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_a^\infty\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^t}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $(1)$ also needs justification as to why you can switch the derivative and integral.